# The alternative of lookbehind

Tags: regex

I have a string: **`12345 XD Hi12345678ab666666cd987654321`**.
I want to obtain **`12345678`** and **`666666`** and discard `98765432` or `87654321`, which I could do that by **lookahead** and **lookbehind** like `(?<!\d)\d{6,8}(?!\d)`.

The problem is VBA do not support **lookbehind**.
How do I rewrite the pattern to obtain what I want?

Comment: There is no `87654321` in your string.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Last 8 characters in my string is `87654321`.

Comment: Right, missed that. Does my answer help?

Comment: Can VBA support  match reset? Then you cn try `\D\K(\d{6,8})(?=\D)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple alternative would be to match `\D` and use a capturing group for the numbers.

`(?:\D|^)(\d{6,8})(?!\d)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9TYlKw/1/)

You can access the first capturing group with `match.Submatches(0)`

Comment: @Onyambu Where exactly is the lookbehind in this answer?

Comment: He tries to avoid the use of lookbehind because it does not seem to be supported on VBA

Comment: Yeah, I was replying to @Onyambu who deleted his comment. His comment stated that you had used a lookbehind where, in fact, you have not.

Comment: @julio Your answer obtain some matches which leading a letter.  How can I obtain the numbers only?

Comment: @PaichengWu It is a correct answer. You just need to access `match.Submatches(0)`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I'll add that to the answer